# Edge not starting after msedgedriver.exe is started on 'protected' server (C# / Selenium)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, windows-server-2019, selenium-edgedriver

I have a testautomation framework which is working fine on my own system.
It uses drivermanager to fetch the right version of msedgedriver.exe and then is supposed to launch edge and starts testing with the scripts.
This works fine on my own laptop.

This code is now on a server of a client of mine.
The server has Windows Server 2019 installed and is behind a proxy.The user has local administrator rights.
On this server, when I launch a test with VS 2022 msedgedriver.exe starts (taskmanager) but the test fails:

```
Message: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:53325/

Stack Trace: 
DriverService.Start()
DriverServiceCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary2 parameters) 
WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities) 
WebDriver.ctor(ICommandExecutor executor, ICapabilities capabilities) 
ChromiumDriver.ctor(ChromiumDriverService service, ChromiumOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout) 
EdgeDriver.ctor(EdgeDriverService service, EdgeOptions options, TimeSpan commandTimeout) 
EdgeDriver.ctor(EdgeDriverService service, EdgeOptions options) BrowserFeature.OpenBrowser() line 109
```

The msedgedriver.exe is reachable through edge on http://localhost:53325/ (or any other port it starts) but Edge itself never starts.

The code used to start:

```
var edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
edgeOptions.Proxy = proxy;
edgeOptions.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Driver, LogLevel.All);
edgeOptions.AddArguments("--no-sandbox");

var service = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.UseVerboseLogging = true;
edgeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", Settings.DownloadFolder);
                   
Driver = new EdgeDriver(service, edgeOptions);
```

What we've already tried:

1. Running VS 2022 in admin modus
2. Adding HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY and NO_PROXY to the system variables with HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY filled with the proxy server and NO_PROXY filled with localhost and 127.0.0.1
3. Checked whether msedgedriver is already running or is started multiple times. This is not the case.
4. Added proxyserver in the code, even for the DriverManager. This should not be the issue since msedgedriver is downloaded correctly and DriverManager takes the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY values from the system.
5. Dismissing the DriverManager and integrating the correct driver (and starting it) directly
6. Point 5 with Chrome instead of edge which results in the exact same error
7. Driver versioning combined with the version of the driver is correct
8. Windows firewall has been killed in the hopes that that was blocking something
9. Added the DeveloperToolsAvailability variable to the registry wity value "1" so that developertools is enabled for MSEdge

We are kind of clueless since the same code is working on my own system and on another server of my own. But it seems that at the client there is something configured that is blocking the start of the browser, whether it is Chrome or Edge. My take is that either the start of the browser is blocked, or the communication with the driver (which apparently is running since I can see it in edge and chrome (the localhost: is reachable).

But with everything we have already tried we are kind of in the dark.

I dove into this further and came across the following code which checks whether the start of the driver was succesfull (part of OpenQA.Selenium.DriverService):

```
       protected virtual bool IsInitialized
        {
            get
            {
                bool result = false;
                try
                {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                    try
                    {
                        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
                        httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0);
                        Uri serviceHealthUri = new Uri(ServiceUrl, new Uri(DriverCommand.Status, UriKind.Relative));
                        using HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = Task.Run(async () => await httpClient.GetAsync(serviceHealthUri)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                        result = httpResponseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK && httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType!.MediaType!.StartsWith("application/json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                        return result;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (httpClient != null)
                        {
                            ((IDisposable)httpClient).Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) when (ex is HttpRequestException || ex is TaskCanceledException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
```

What i've done next is I fixated the portnumber, created a powershell script doing practically the same as the above. It it sais (even before the test fails with the error OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:5588/) that it is running.

The powershell script that I am running simultaniously from the developer powershell in Visual Studio:

```
# Set the URL for the WebDriver service status check
$serviceUrl = "http://localhost:5588/status"

# Attempt to make an HTTP GET request to the service URL
try {
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $serviceUrl -TimeoutSec 5

    # Check if the response is successful (status code 200)
    if ($response.StatusCode -eq 200) {
        # Check the content type (case-insensitive)
        $contentType = $response.Headers["Content-Type"]
        if ($contentType -eq "application/json" -or $contentType -ilike "application/json*") {
            Write-Host "WebDriver service is running and responsive."
        } else {
            Write-Host "Unexpected content type: $contentType"
        }
    } else {
        Write-Host "Error: $($response.StatusCode)"
    }
} catch {
    Write-Host "Error: $_"
}

echo $response.StatusCode
```

Which results in the following response:

```
WebDriver service is running and responsive.
200
```

Apparently the check which is being done from the code is not able to reach http://localhost:5588 ??

Comment: "This code is now on a server of a client. " - Selenium runs in headless mode when running on a server.

Comment: Apologies. It's on a server of a client of mine. We are running this code from VS 2022 by executing the test from the test explorer.

Comment: try double-clicking on msedgedriver.exe to run it.  See if console gives you a more detailed error message.  If that runs without error, it's probably the code that sets the proxy.  You shouldn't need that for the driver itself, and I think you'd set that as an argument....: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/376056/microsoft-edge-seleniumtools-assign-a-custom-proxy  You may also want to check the machine's "hosts" file for any existing localhost re-mappings.

Comment: Thanks @pcalkins for your response. Hostfile is empty. And the driver is available through http://localhost:<portnr> and /status also gives us that it is available for new sessions. Next to that the hosts file is default (empty).

Comment: try without any edgeoptions set.  Also if the IDE is also launching the site be aware that it is also going to run a localhost server.  If that's the case, I believe you should be setting "debuggerAddress" to match the debug port of the IDE for the site.  (This let's you integrate with the IDE's debugger.)  It's something like: options.AddAdditionalCapability("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:5555");

Comment: Thanks again @pcalkins for your response. The site is not hosted on the same server so that is not the case. Removing all edgeoptions and thus starting as "Driver = new EdgeDriver(service);" did not give any other result. 
msedgedriver.exe starts and is available through a browsersession. But the browser itself does not start from the test and it all ends with the error that it cannot start the driver service on http://localhost

Comment: Not sure what's happening here.  Check driver version against browser version.  You may also want to try with just var Driver = new EdgeDriver();   Try sending binary location of Edge browser executable... might also check to be sure that only one test file is run in VS test explorer.  Maybe also check permissions of the edgedriver executable.  (Where is BrowserFeature.OpenBrowser() coming from? maybe include that code in your post?)

Comment: @pcalkins thanks for taking the time to help out. The driververions are correct and match the version of Edge installed. I've added the path to msedge.exe to the PATH environment variable and am able to start it from the command line from any directory now. But that doesnt help either.

Comment: what happens when you open command prompt and type: MicrosoftEdge.exe --devtools-server-port 53325 ?

Comment: Running msedge.exe --devtools-server-port <msedgedriver-portnumber> (in this case port 57186) opens an edge browser navigating to http://0.0.223.98 ?

Comment: hmm... not sure why it would do that... a gateway of some kind?  When you try to use ChromeDriver instead, are you getting the same errors?  Normally what happens when running the driver executable is that it will launch the browser in dev-mode for wire-protocol.  The browser will then launch and drop a file which contains the sessionID used for the webdriver to communicate with the browser and vice versa.  The webdriver reads that value from the file and then starts communicating using that sessionID.

Comment: After re-reading, I see you've already tried Chromedriver.  It sounds like there might be a WAN that routes local addresses to other machines?  (a pure guess... I really have no idea what's happening)

Comment: We have opened a Microsoft ticket. As stated at the end of the post (an update) I am able to connect with a Powershell script from Visual Studio while the test is loading and it is actually succeeding(the Powershell script) while the test fails moments later.